# Reverse geocoding, language doesn't change when user changes language in Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reverse-geocoding

when I'm doing a reverse geocoding request and the iPhone's language is set to Spanish, reverse geocoding gives back the address in Spanish as expected. 
When I now change the language to German in the iPhone's settings and restart the app, the address when doing another reverse geocoding is still in Spanish, even though I changed all language settings properly.

Can anyone please help out?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart the phone. Even if you restart the app, sometimes the settings don't stick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even after a restart of the iPhone the city's name after a new reverse geocode is still in the old language...

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Let me get back to you. Sorry for the bunk answer!

Comment: The solution was to delete the app and install it again. Somehow the language got stuck within the app. Thanks for your effort dokun1!